# Building a responsive navbar with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a website using Bootstrap 3. My problem is that the navbar on the webpage shows next to the brand div, which is floated left. So the navbar doesn't have enough space when you are using your mobile phone to access the webpage and you have to scroll in the menu.

**HTML**

```
   <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">

           <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>

          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">FUTURE LOGO</a> 

           <div class="navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                 <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Domu</a></li>


                 <li><a href="obsahmp.html">Obsah MP</a></li>

                 <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Responzivní webdesign<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="responzivniwebdesign.html">Co to vlastně je?</a></li>
                      <li><a href="webovarozvrzeni.html">Webová rozvržení</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Tvorba responzivního webu</a></li>

                      <li class="divider"></li>

                      <li class="dropdown-header">CSS frameworky</li>
                      <li><a href="#">Co, jak a proč?</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Twitter bootstrap</a></li>
                    </ul><!-- End dropdown-menu-->
                 </li><!-- End dropdown-->

                 <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Použité komponenty<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="navbar.html">Navbar</a></li>
                      <li><a href="dropdown.html">Dropdown</a></li>
                      <li><a href="carousel.html">Carousel</a></li>

                      <li class="divider"></li>

                      <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdown-header</li>
                      <li><a href="#">Subsection</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Subsection</a></li>
                    </ul><!-- End dropdown-menu-->
                 </li><!-- End dropdown-->
              </ul><!--End nav-->
           </div><!-- End navbar-collapse-->
        </div> <!-- End container-->
    </div> <!-- End navbar-->
```

You can also check the navbar here: www.tomas-nosek.moxo.cz. Just rezise the browser window and you will see the problem I have.

Comment: [responsive utilities for bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) . You should just need to add one of those for your use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

add this `<div class="visible-xs clearfix"></div>`   to end of  `<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">FUTURE LOGO</a>`

this to clear your floating css on small devices,

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">

           <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>

          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">FUTURE LOGO</a> 
            <div class="visible-xs  clearfix"></div>
           <div class="navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                 <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Domu</a></li>


                 <li><a href="obsahmp.html">Obsah MP</a></li>

                 <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Responzivní webdesign<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="responzivniwebdesign.html">Co to vlastně je?</a></li>
                      <li><a href="webovarozvrzeni.html">Webová rozvržení</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Tvorba responzivního webu</a></li>

                      <li class="divider"></li>

                      <li class="dropdown-header">CSS frameworky</li>
                      <li><a href="#">Co, jak a proč?</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Twitter bootstrap</a></li>
                    </ul><!-- End dropdown-menu-->
                 </li><!-- End dropdown-->

                 <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Použité komponenty<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="navbar.html">Navbar</a></li>
                      <li><a href="dropdown.html">Dropdown</a></li>
                      <li><a href="carousel.html">Carousel</a></li>

                      <li class="divider"></li>

                      <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdown-header</li>
                      <li><a href="#">Subsection</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Subsection</a></li>
                    </ul><!-- End dropdown-menu-->
                 </li><!-- End dropdown-->
              </ul><!--End nav-->
           </div><!-- End navbar-collapse-->
        </div> <!-- End container-->
    </div> <!-- End navbar-->
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UI_Designer/c11d8d9k/)**

Answer (score 0):

You want to put a "clear:left" in the navbar on mobile.
Also maybe add 'col-xs-12' as a class to the container with the menu.

Basically you have to break the menu to a new line.

Comment: So I should implement some kind of media queries into my CSS? @Daniel Böttner

Comment: media queries are already used in bootstrap.
Take a look at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid again.

There are different classes to control the behavior of an element on different screen sizes.

large screen:
col-lg-6 = makes an element take up 50% space of an grid of 12

medium size screen:
col-md-8 = added on the same element would make the element take up 8 of 12 units

col-sm-12 = 100% width an small screens
col-xs-12 = 100% width on very small screens

xs is redundant here because sm-12 already goes for full width.